# Definition help count_engcons

Tags: python

> Define a function called `count_engcons()` which takes a string and
>   returns the number of consonants in the string (uppercase or
>   lowercase). For this problem, you may consider only letters in the
>   English language alphabet only. Also, for this problem "Y" is
>   considered a consonant (...not a vowel!). So for example
>   `count_engcons("Tessellated?")` should return `7`, and
>   `count_engcons("Aeiou!")` should return `0`. You must use a `for` loop, and
>   you are not allowed to use the `.count()` method on this problem.

I tried this:

```
def count_engcons(x):
    vowels = ("aeiou")
    count = 0

    for count_engcons in text:
        if not count_engcons in vowels:
            count += 1
    return x
```

However, it causes an error.

Thanks, jonrsharpe for the downvote.

Comment: This isn't a tutorial service. If you have a problem with the code you've written, give a [mcve]; *"causes an error"* is no use whatsoever. That said, you should reread the variable names in your function...

Comment: Don't reuse names.  `count_engcons` is already the name of your function, so don't use it in your `for` clause

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were checking if a character wasn't a vowel, so it would give bad results for characters such as `!` or `?`, you were also trying to access the string with different variable names (`x` and `text`), which makes no sense.

```
def count_engcons(text):
    consonants = "bcdfghijklmnpqrstvwxyz"
    count = 0

    for c in text.lower():
        if c in consonants:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: Can you also help me with this problem?

Comment: Define a function called shortest() that takes a tuple of strings, and returns the shortest string in the tuple.
So for example shortest( ("xyz", "w", "abc") ) should return "w".
If there are multiple strings of the same maximum length, then we don't care which one your function returns. So for example, if shortest( ("uno", "dva", "drei", "vier") ) returns "uno", that's fine, and if it returns"dva", that's okay too.

Comment: @Joseph it's not clear why you think SO is here to help you cheat on your homework; it isn't. I'd encourage you to take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: Thanks, a lot jonrsharpe. wow, fantastic! you don't even give me suggestions and clue but you say this. Like you did nothing you just say mean things to people. You're the type of person who would discourage people from joining computer science.

Comment: @Joseph I've given you two suggestions. I would certainly not encourage you to waste your time and that of the faculty members if you intend to farm your work out to SO rather than run the risk of actually learning something.

Comment: I already got help from my friends. Go downvote other people and ruin other people's life.